# Z3 patterns and injectivity

Tags: z3, smt

In the Z3 tutorial, section 13.2.3, there is a nice example on how to reduce the number of patterns that have to be instantiated when dealing with the axiomatisation of injectivity. In the example, the function f  that has to be stated injective, takes an object of type A as input and return an object of type B. As far as I understand the sorts A and B are disjunct.

I have an SMT problem (FOL+EUF) on which Z3 seems not to terminate, and I am trying to isolate the cause. I have a function f:A->A that I assert being injective. Could the problem be that the domain and codomain of f coincide?

Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

Comment: Could you post the example? Thanks.

Comment: You can see the code here: http://rise4fun.com/Z3/V8F4  - thanks for your swift reply!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Z3 does not terminate because it keeps trying to build an interpretation for the problem.
Satisfiable problems containing injectivity axiom are usually hard for Z3. 
They usually fall in a class of problems that can't be decided by Z3
The [Z3 guide](http://rise4fun.com/Z3/tutorial/guide) describes most of the classes that can be decided by Z3.
Moreover, Z3 can produce models for infinite domains such as integers and reals. However, in most cases, the functions produced by Z3 have *finite* ranges. For example, the quantifier `forall x, y: x <= y implies f(x) <= f(y)` can be satisfied by assigning `f` to a function that has a finite range. More information can be found in [this article](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/leonardo/files/ci.pdf). Unfortunately, injectivity usually requires a range that is as "big" as the domain. Moreover, it is very easy to write axioms that can only be satisfied by an infinite universe. For example, the formula

```
(assert
   (forall ((d1 Value)(d2 Value)(d3 Value)(d4 Value))
      (! (=>
         (and (= (ENC d1 d2) (ENC d3 d4)))
         (and (= d1 d3) (= d2 d4))
      )
      :pattern ((ENC d1 d2) (ENC d3 d4)))
   )
)
```

can only be satisfied if the universe of `Value` has one element or is infinite.
Another problem is combining the injectivity axiom for a function `f` with axioms of the form `forall x: f(x) != a`. If `f` is a function from `A` to `A`, then the formula can only be satisfied if `A` has an infinite universe.

That being said, we can prevent the non-termination by reducing the amount of "resources" used by the Z3 model finder for quantified formulas. The options

```
(set-option :auto-config false)
(set-option :mbqi-max-iterations 10)
```

If we use these options, Z3 will terminate in your example, but will return `unknown`. It also returns a "candidate" model. It is not really a model since it does not satisfy all universal quantifiers in the problem. The option

```
(set-option :mbqi-trace true)
```

will instruct Z3 to display which quantifiers were not satisfied.

Regarding the example in section 13.2.3, the function may use the same input and return types. Using the trick described in this section will only help unsatisfiable instances. Z3 will also not terminate (for satisfiable formulas) if you re-encode the injectivity axioms using this trick.

Note that the tutorial you cited is very old, and contains outdated information.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply! I got rid of the non-termination by explicitly introducing a predicate that undertakes the role of a domain, thus cutting down the infinity by explicitly setting a cardinality constraint.