# How to declare or check a one-to-one function?

Tags: c++, z3

In z3's C++ API, a function is delared as:

```
func_decl f = function("f", I, I, I);
```

which means a function take input `(int, int)` and returns `int`.

Can I declare an one-to-one(bijective) function or can I enforce a function to be one-to-one (bijective)?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no built-in way of declaring a function to be a bijection. You can axiomatise it yourself, however:

```
(declare-sort X)
(declare-sort Y)

(declare-fun f (X) Y)

(assert (forall ((y Y))
  (exists ((x X))
    (and
      (= (f x) y)
      (forall ((z X))
        (implies
          (not (= x z))
          (not (= (f z) y))))))))
```

And use it as follows:

```
(declare-const x1 X)
(declare-const x2 X)
(declare-const y1 Y)
(declare-const y2 Y)

(assert (= (f x1) y1))
(check-sat) ; sat

(push)
  (assert (= (f x2) y1))
  (check-sat) ; sat
(pop)

(assert (not (= x1 x2)))
(check-sat) ; sat

(push)
  (assert (= (f x2) y1))
  (check-sat) ; unsat
(pop)
```

Try it [online here](http://rise4fun.com/Z3/Yhil).

I am not sure how the performance of this encoding is. Alternating quantifiers often cause problems in automatic theorem proving, and the axiom above doesn't even have patterns/triggers. My hunch is, that the axiom is ok as long as you provide "enough" information, for example, `x1`, `x2`, `(= (f x1) y1)` and `(not (= x1 x2))`. I am not sure how well model-finding will work here, though.

Comment: See also this q/a for some details regarding decidability, performance, and model finding of injective functions, some of which will be relevant for bijections: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13879605/z3-patterns-and-injectivity/13889777#13889777 . There is some ability for model finding to work at least for finite sorts, see, e.g.: http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/iOAs

Comment: @Taylor Thanks for providing the link!