# Using functions, reals, and quantifiers in Z3

Tags: z3

I'm trying to pose queries to Z3 that involve uninterpreted functions (always with domain int), reals, and quantifiers. I know that adding quantifiers will often lead to `unknown` results, but I was surprised at how quickly this happened:

```
(declare-fun $in1 (Int) Real)
(declare-fun $in2 (Int) Real)
(assert (< ($in1 0) ($in2 0)))
(assert (forall (($$out Real))
  (not (and (< ($in1 0) $$out) (< $$out ($in2 0))))))
(check-sat)
```

This query should result in `unsat` but instead times out with `unknown`. Is there a flag or option I could set which might lead Z3 to solve this query? I'd hate to have to go through and flatten all my uninterpreted functions into scalars, but that is something I could do.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it looks like this is a hard instance for Z3. E-matching fails to prove unsatisfiability and after that MBQI essentially starts to enumerate real numbers, which will not lead to the goal here.

If you just want a quick result but don't care about unknowns, simply set smt.mbqi.max_iterations to a small enough value. You can also try to help the e-matching engine by providing instantiations patterns (see e.g., the [quantifier section in the Z3 guide](http://rise4fun.com/Z3/tutorialcontent/guide#h28)).

There's also a related question that might help understanding: [Z3 patterns and injectivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13879605/z3-patterns-and-injectivity)

Answer (score 0):

Arie Gurfinkel pointed out that  `(check-sat-using qe-sat)` solves this problem.